# systemd is blocking port 69 so I'm not able start atftpd

Tags: systemd, tftp

For TP-Link router recovery, I'm trying to create TFTP server on my laptop with atftpd. But when I try to run it with `sudo atftpd --daemon --no-fork --logfile - /srv/tftp`, It says it can't bin port 69/udp. When I check listening ports with `sudo lsof -i:69`, systemd process with pid 1 is listening on *:tftp on IPv6. How can I disable this? I obviously can't just kill systemd. I'm using Debian 12.

Comment: Your laptop is already running a tftp server, why try installing & running another? It you really want to run atftpd, then try `systemdctl stop tftp` first.